# Галерея\каталог javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap

Как реализовать переход на следующую страницу без перезагрузки страницы?
Есть примеры кода?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: AJAX или FetchAPI вам в помощь!!!

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужно удалить контейнер, содержащий изображения и paging и сгенерировать / подгрузить новый контейнер с новым содержимым.

Можно так-же всё загрузить заранее и показывать при необходимости, как описано в ответах на [этот вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31920360/1597497).

Например:

```js
//Pagination
 pageSize = 8;

 var pageCount =  $(".line-content").length / pageSize;
    
     for(var i = 0 ; i<pageCount;i++){
        
       $("#pagin").append('<li><a href="#">'+(i+1)+'</a></li> ');
     }
        $("#pagin li").first().find("a").addClass("current")
    showPage = function(page) {
     $(".line-content").hide();
     $(".line-content").each(function(n) {
         if (n >= pageSize * (page - 1) && n < pageSize * page)
             $(this).show();
     });        
 }
    
 showPage(1);

 $("#pagin li a").click(function() {
     $("#pagin li a").removeClass("current");
     $(this).addClass("current");
     showPage(parseInt($(this).text())) 
 });
```

```css
.current {
  color: green;
}

#pagin li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="line-content">1 I have some content</div>
<div class="line-content">2 I have some content</div>
<div class="line-content">3 I have some content</div>
<div class="line-content">4 I have some content</div>
<div class="line-content">5 I have some content</div>
<div class="line-content">6 I have some content</div>
<div class="line-content">7 I have some content</div>
<div class="line-content">8 I have some content</div>
<div class="line-content">9 I have some content</div>
<div class="line-content">10 I have some content</div>
<div class="line-content">11 I have some content</div>
<div class="line-content">12 I have some content</div>

<ul id="pagin">
         
</ul>
```